# Can't get a trigger box to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a small 'trigger box' that will open upon click. It used to work a while ago, but I'm not sure what is exactly wrong now.

I've learned a bit of HTML and CSS so I understand what's going on with those sections, but I barely know Javascript. So everything within the script selector is new to me; someone else online provided it and I'm trying to understand it. Reading the syntax, I think I know what's happening, but I still don't know what the problem exactly is.

Here's the code I have. Yes, it's all in 1 HTML file because this is for just 1 page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> This is the Title </title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { color:#666; font:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
        h1 { font-size:36px; color:#333; margin:0 0 15px 0; padding:0 0 15px 0; border-bottom: solid 1px #e1e1e1; }
        .awesomeBox { border:solid 1px #cacaca; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #bbb; padding:15px; margin:20px; width:400px; }
        .trigger { cursor:pointer; }

        /* this is all you need to make the hidden box hidden :) */
        .hiddenBox { display:none; }

        /* we put a little style to the trigger */
        .box { position:relative; }
        .box .trigger { font-size:12px; background:#cacaca; padding:5px 10px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; position:absolute; bottom:-42px; right:0; }
        .box .hiddenBox { background:#f9f9f9; color:#000; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
</style>

<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() { 

            $(".trigger").on("click", function() { 
                $(".hiddenBox").toggle();                                                   
            });             
        });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="awesomeBox">

    <h1 class="trigger">Le awesome Page</h1>

    <div class="box">The area where you could type a lot of text but also want to hide some text<br>

        <p>So, user will press the read more button.</p> <a href="#" class="trigger">Read more &raquo;</a> 

        <div class="hiddenBox"> 

            <p>A lot of text in this hidden box and ...
            a lot 
            alot more
            fsdfsd
            </p>

            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="100%" /> 
       </div>             
    </div>        
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FpL2H/

Comment: Where did you copy this from?

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex6pK/

Try viewing this page in Google Chrome, Right click on any part of the visible page, and Inspect Element, look for Javascript errors there.

I suspect that perhaps

```
    $(function() { 

        $(".trigger").on("click", function() { 
            $(".hiddenBox").toggle();                                                   
        });             
    });
```

is being called before Jquery is loaded

Comment: Jquery something i have to add or install? i can't get it to work in either chrome or Firefox

Comment: `<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` should load your jQuery, but perhaps you are working from a place where there is no Internet or something... you may want to manually download it and link to it locally instead of through Google APIs...

Comment: Weird... For some reason this isn't working for me on 2 computers... Is there anything I need to do other than just simply running the HTML file in a browser? I still have Google hosting the jQuery script as well